# PDO Invalid parameter number with named params?

Tags: php, pdo

**EDIT**
As someone pointed out below, it was a typo, please ignore this, complete user error

---

I thought this was a little weird, I was under the impression that a `:param` could be used multiple times?

Class:

```
Final Class StageMapper Extends DataMapper
{
    public static function push($vendor)
    {
        $st = self::$db->prepare(
            'UPDATE footable SET site = :site, hash = :hash WHERE site = :site AND id = :id'
        );

        $st->execute(array(
            ':site'         => $vendor->s,
            ':hash'         => $vendor->h,
            ':uid'          => $vendor->i,
        ));
    }
}
```

Input:

```
// some rand vals
$vendor = (object) array (
  's'   => 'domain.com',
  'h'   => '180b35',
  'i'   => '1',
);

DataMapper::init();          // kick off a new connection via PDO
StageMapper::push($vendor);  // do stuff =P
```

Seems strange that it would throw me this error since we're already bound for `:site` (which is what I believe is throwing it)

Could someone explain to me what is going on with my bound parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a typo. :uid binding, :id marker.

Comment: Hahaha, holy crap you're right, man... what an oversight ;) Plus 1 and waiting to accept

Answer (score 0):

If you use emulated prepares, you can use a named parameter multiple times. If you use "real" prepares, you cannot.